# Cognos Crosstab

Tags: crosstab, cognos

I am trying to generate a crosstab of data in Report Studio but failed.

The data in the list I have is:

- ID, Product, Grade
- 1, Product1, D
- 1, Product2, C
- 1, Product3, D
- 2, Product1, C
- 2, Product2, C
- 2, Product3, A

---

I want a crosstab of:

- ID, Product1, Product2, Product3
- 1, D,C, D
- 2, C, C, A

But the crosstab I generate in Cognos gives me either all blank or a count or sum of "Grade".

- ID, Product1, Product2, Product3
- 1,
- 2,

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Best,
Tom

Comment: Are you able to show any of the things you've already tried?

Answer (score 3):

Crosstab works only for numbers.
So measure for crosstab should not be A, B, C.

1. Use number as a measure (A = 1, B = 2 etc), use MAX or MIN as an aggregate.
2. Then convert your number to text inside cell. For example, change the Source Type property to Report Expression and write suitable formula. (Or unlock cell and drag Query Calculation inside)

You can't do things like

ID|Product1|Product2|Product3

1 | D,A | C | D

2 | C | C | A

simply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need to use a case statement for your product grade columns:

```
ID     PRODUCT1        
1      case when Product = 'Product1' then grade else null end
```

You may need to wrap the case statement in a `MAX`, not sure without trying it.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said you need it looks like a list is the best option.

```
    ID | Case when [Product] = 'Product1' then [grade] end | same for product 2 and 3
```